Consistently align text at different rotations with CSS
I am creating a grid using an HTML <table>. I have labels for each row, column, and diagonal. In particular, I would like the label text to be aligned with the edge of the grid, so larger numbers expand outwards. Here's a rough design of what I'd like to achieve:

I'm struggling to make this work in CSS for the diagonal and vertical labels. I've tried different combinations of text-align, vertical-align, and transform rules.

This is relatively trivial with some transform-origin rotate and translate, along with a little absolute positioning with rows / cells having relative positioning. If you dont get any answers I'll take some time tomorrow to provide a more detailed explanation <3

An example of some of your 'attempts' would help to nail down a solution for you.

position: absolute seems to be the missing ingredient! I'll try to write up a full answer when I've cleaned my code up some more

It would be easier to help if you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and use Stack Snippets to make a live demo.

I've come up with a working example using display: inline and position: absolute:


.number-vertical {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.number-diagonal {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.number-other-diagonal {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.number-horizontal {
  text-align: right;
}

.cell-rotated-center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 6ch;
}

.cell-rotated-right {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.number-input {
  width: 4ch;
  height: 4ch;
  text-align: center;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell-rotated-right">
        <div class="number-diagonal">
          <span>10</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-rotated-center">
        <div class="number-vertical">
          <span>72</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-rotated-center">
        <div class="number-vertical">
          <span>720</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-rotated-center">
        <div class="number-vertical">
          <span>100000</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="number-horizontal">
          <span>36</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="number-horizontal">
          <span>360</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="number-horizontal">
          <span>360000</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="number-input" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell-rotated-right">
        <div class="number-other-diagonal">
          <span>5000</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




I'm glad you got it working for yourself. Thanks for sharing your answer <3
